# Debugging in Chrome to find what PHP file created a specific HTML

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, debugging

when i'm debugging an html file in chrome, and that same HTML file is created by a PHP file, is there a way to know what PHP file created that HTML?

Thanks.

Comment: Only your server knows which server-side file has generated the HTML code (not a file, in that case you already have the info?). If you have a routing file, .htaccess rules or something similar somewhere you should be able to search for the path in your project.

Comment: Generally what I do is search all the PHP source files for a tidbit of html that makes up the page like `<div id="mydiv">`.  Dreamweaver is great for something like this because you can perform a text search on every file of your site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you simply have to tell PHP to reveal itself within your HTML code like this:

*I highly recommend setting some sort of debugging flag so that you can toggle this as needed and so that if the code leaks into production then it should hopefully be secure.*

**header.php**

```
<!-- <?php echo (DEBUGGING_FLAG ? __FILE__.' started this HTML' : ''); ?> -->
<div class="nav_bar">
    <?php include('header_links.php'); ?>
</div>
<!-- <?php echo (DEBUGGING_FLAG ? __FILE__.' finished this HTML' : ''); ?> -->
```

**header_links.php**

```
<!-- <?php echo (DEBUGGING_FLAG ? __FILE__.' started this HTML' : ''); ?> -->
<a href="">Link1</a>
<a href="">Link2</a>
<a href="">Link3</a>
<!-- <?php echo (DEBUGGING_FLAG ? __FILE__.' finished this HTML' : ''); ?> -->
```

You the outputted HTML would look like:

```
<!-- /path/to/header.php started this HTML -->
<div class="nav_bar">
    <!-- /path/to/header_links.php started this HTML -->
    <a href="">Link1</a>
    <a href="">Link2</a>
    <a href="">Link3</a>
    <!-- /path/to/header_links.php finished this HTML -->
</div>
<!-- /path/to/header.php finished this HTML -->
```

Comment: Sidenote: just because one can do this, doesn't mean one should. It probably is better to set a debug flag in the project and only do this if debugging otherwise you end up transferring data to users which is only meaningful to you and to none of the users.

Comment: @apokryfos Very true, I've updated the answer to reflect your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't.

Your php file is sent to the server and the server spits out the html. 
So the server is the only one who knows which file has generated the code.